# Change the url after clicking the submit button

Tags: php

I have a form that filters the products by some characters such as size/price etc..
I would like to change the url variables values according to the filter result for example:

Before submit:

```
www.exmaple.com/product.php
```

after submit

```
www.example.com/product.php?size=1&price=300
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
if(isset($submit))
{
//After clicking the button , do some operations here....

//Your code...

//More code...

header("location:product.php?size=1&price=300");
}
```

**EDIT :**

This is most common error check this [`thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php/).   Also, if that doesn't work. Replace your header with

`echo "<script>document.location.href=product.php?size=1&price=300</script>";`

Comment: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent ...